# Detect Other Button click (NSUserNotification)

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsusernotification

I've searched all over the internet but the only method found was by looping through

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center didDeliverNotification:(NSUserNotification *)notification
```

just as shown in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21365269/1795083

However, my app sometimes displays multiple notifications at a short interval, so this isn't really efficient nor effective. How does the mail app handle it when the trash button is pressed. There has to be at least a private method that's called. Has anyone ever came across it? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After... uhm.... "checking" out the mail app's code... I found a suspicious function in their notification controller class...

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(NSUserNotificationCenter *)center didDismissAlert:(NSUserNotification *)alert
```

I have no idea why apple don't want to add this function to the NSUserNotificationDelegate... but I tested this out in my app and it works!!!

Comment: Yeah, that works. I wonder if it could get your app reject from MAS.

Comment: Where/how can you get Mail app code? Have you reverse engineered it?

Comment: @VitoValov yep I reverse engineered the binary using Hopper Disassembly

Answer (score 3):

**Swift >= 4** version:

```
@objc
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: NSUserNotificationCenter, didDismissAlert notification: NSUserNotification)
```

Make sure you add the `@objc` annotation, otherwise the objective-C runtime won't be able to see your delegate method.